# Move up fixed positioned div when resizing browser

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a div with a fixed top position. It starts almost in the middle of the screen, so if the browser windows is too small, since the scrollbar is disabled, part of the div disappears.

I need to use the "top" property instead of "bottom" because the div must be aligned  with the top margin, and depending on its content may have different heights. I think I'd need something like a "min-bottom" property.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the div to be centered horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Code, please! Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it - sorry I only know the jQuery way to do it. But I am sure you could look up the non jquery way for each of these steps and implement it.

1. Bind to the resize event of the browser
2. On resize get the height of the window
3. If the div isn't on screen then adjust the top css property

Untested code

```
$(window).resize( function() {
    var mydiv = $('#mydiv');
    var bottomOfMyDiv = $(mydiv).offset().top + $(mydiv).height();
    var bottomOfWindow = $(window).height();
    if (bottomOfMyDiv > bottomOfWindow) {
        //adjust top css property
        $(mydiv).css('top', topvalue);
    }
});
```